# Enable logging in spring boot actuator health check API

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, spring-boot-actuator

I am using Spring boot Actuator API for my [project](https://imobilenumbertracker.com/) the having a health check endpoint, and enabled it by :

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=healthcheck
```

Mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html)

Now I want to enable log in my application log file when ever the status of this above `/healthcheck` fails and print the entire response from this end point.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way is to extend the actuator endpoint with [`@EndpointWebExtension`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/web/annotation/EndpointWebExtension.html). You can do the following;

```
@Component
@EndpointWebExtension(endpoint = HealthEndpoint.class)
public class HealthEndpointWebExtension {

    private HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;
    private HealthStatusHttpMapper statusHttpMapper;

    // Constructor

    @ReadOperation
    public WebEndpointResponse<Health> health() {
        Health health = this.healthEndpoint.health();
        Integer status = this.statusHttpMapper.mapStatus(health.getStatus());
        // log here depending on health status.
        return new WebEndpointResponse<>(health, status);
    }
}
```

More about actuator endpoint extending [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators), at **4.8. Extending Existing Endpoints**

Comment: In `spring-boot-actuator 2.2.5`, the Extension to `HealthEndpoint.class` seem to already exist/defined in `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointWebExtensionConfiguration` as a Bean of type `org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension` . Not allowing to have more than one Extension for the same `HealthEndpoint`.  The spring boot app does not start. Did this code work for anyone?

Comment: @madhav-turangi I managed to do this by extending ReactiveHealthEndpointWebExtension(registry, groups). Then adding the annotations as above.

Comment: Does the above code get executed when you view `[myhost:port]/actuator/health` from a browser?  It doesn't for me.  Is there another way I should get this to execute when testing it?

Answer (score 3):

The above answers did not work for me. I implemented the below and it works.  When you view `[myhost:port]/actuator/health` from your browser the below will execute.  You can also add `healthCheckLogger` to your readiness/liveness probes so it executes periodically.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class HealthCheckLogger implements HealthIndicator
{
   @Lazy
   @Autowired
   private HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;

   @Override
   public Health health()
   {
      log.info("DB health: {}", healthEndpoint.healthForPath("db"));
      log.info("DB health: {}", healthEndpoint.healthForPath("diskSpace"));
      return Health.up().build();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Extending the `HealthEndpoint` using a `EndpointWebExtension` does not work with newer Spring versions. It's not allowed to override the existing (web-) extension or re-register another one.

Another solution is using a `Filter`. The following implementation logs if the health check fails:

```
public class HealthLoggingFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HealthLoggingFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        // nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseCacheWrapperObject = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
        chain.doFilter(request, responseCacheWrapperObject);

        int status = ((HttpServletResponse) response).getStatus();
        if (status >= 400) { // unhealthy
            byte[] responseArray = responseCacheWrapperObject.getContentAsByteArray();
            String responseStr = new String(responseArray, responseCacheWrapperObject.getCharacterEncoding());
            LOG.warn("Unhealthy. Health check returned: {}", responseStr);
        }

        responseCacheWrapperObject.copyBodyToResponse();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // nothing to do
    }
}
```

The Filter can be registered for the `actuator/health` route using `FilterRegistrationBean`:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<HealthLoggingFilter > loggingFilter(){
    FilterRegistrationBean<HealthLoggingFilter > registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();

    registrationBean.setFilter(new HealthLoggingFilter ());
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/actuator/health");

    return registrationBean;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Webflux this worked for me sample in Kotlin

```
@Component
@EndpointWebExtension(endpoint = HealthEndpoint::class)
    class LoggingReactiveHealthEndpointWebExtension(
          registry: ReactiveHealthContributorRegistry,
          groups: HealthEndpointGroups
    ) : ReactiveHealthEndpointWebExtension(registry, groups) {

    companion object {
        private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingReactiveHealthEndpointWebExtension::class.java)
    }

    override fun health(
        apiVersion: ApiVersion?,
        securityContext: SecurityContext?,
        showAll: Boolean,
        vararg path: String?
    ): Mono<WebEndpointResponse<out HealthComponent>> {
        val health = super.health(apiVersion, securityContext, showAll, *path)

        return health.doOnNext {
            if (it.body.status == UP) {
                logger.info("Health status: {}, {}", it.body.status, ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(it.body))
            }
        }
    }
}
```