# Logging Spring Boot Actuator health status in the application log file

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, spring-boot-actuator

Currently we are using Spring boot actuator **vr 1.5.10** and we can access our health page with **/health** endpoint successfully. But while accessing our health endpoint, we need to log that health status in our application's log file as well so later we can create a Kibana watcher alert based on the status.

I saw that we can extend the health endpoint with "**@EndpointWebExtension**" and log the status there as proposed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54977273/enable-logging-in-spring-boot-actuator-health-check-api). But seems like that is not supported with vr 1.5.10.

Any direction will be really appreciated!

Comment: @buræquete Do you have any idea regarding this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own HealthAggregator and set the Default Spring Aggregator in it and use it.

```
public class OwnHealthAggregator implements HealthAggregator {

private final HealthAggregator defaultHealth;

public OwnHealthAggregator(HealthAggregator defaultHealth) {
    this.defaultHealth = defaultHealth;
}

@Override
public Health aggregate(Map<String, Health> healths) {
    Health result = this.defaultHealth.aggregate(healths);
    // LOG Result here
    return result;
}

}
```

Define a bean and use the default one:

```
@Bean
public HealthAggregator health() {
    return new OwnHealthAggregator(new OrderedHealthAggregator());
}
```

---

Off-topic when you use actuator in this version, you should be careful because many endpoints are enable by default (like /beans, /env, /dump).

Comment: Note that since Spring Boot 2.2.0, HealthAggregator is [deprecated in favor of StatusAggregator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthAggregator.html)

Comment: I just tried on a new spring boot version (2.6.6). There is only StatusAggregator but from Status I do not get enough details for proper logging.
Is there some other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Spring will inject a list of all components that implement a specific interface.
For example:
`private List<HealthIndicator> healthIndicatorList`
will contain every class that implements the `HealthIndicator` class.

You could implement the `HealthIndicator` class in your own component and
then call the `health()` method on each member of the healthIndicatorList and log the result.

Of course,
do not recursively call the `health()` method of your logging health indicator.
Here is some code:

```
@Component
public class LoggingHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator
{
    @Autowired
    private List<HealthIndicator> healthIndicatorList

    @Override
    public Health health()
    {
        for (final HealthIndicator current : healthIndicatorList)
        {
            if (current != this)
            {
                // assumes SLF4j
                logger.log("blam message; {}", current.health());
            }
        }       
        return Health.up().build();
    }
}
```

That code might not work because you class wants all
HealthIndictor implementations and is a HealthIndicator itself.

You might need to add a `@PostConstruct` method and retrieve the list of HealthIndictor components yourself.